# jQuery: find a last child that has specific class

Tags: jquery

If I have deep nested unordered list and I have a reference to the root node, is there a built in way to find a last child of "li" type that has specific css class? For example if I have a tree view branch 5 levels deep, and branch is expanded down to thrid level, levels 1,2,3 will have a class "collapsable". Now I want to find a last "li" in this case on level 3 that has this class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not too hard:

```
$("li.someclass", rootOfList).last()
```

searches `rootOfList` for the last `li` with class `someclass`

Comment: Yes. If you're using 1.3 you can use $("li.someclass:last", rootOfList) instead.

Comment: how about this solution ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/10539199/4425004