# Using jQuery to see if a div has a child with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div `#popup` that is dynamically filled with several paragraphs with the class `.filled-text`. I'm trying to get jQuery to tell me if `#popup` has one of these paragraphs in it.

I have this code:

```
$("#text-field").keydown(function(event) {
    if($('#popup').has('p.filled-text')) {
        console.log("Found");
     }
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking only for a **child** or for any **descendant** (child, grandchild, great grandchild, etc). The question title currently says "child" but the answers appear to talk about arbitrary descendants.

Comment: At the time I believe I was specifically looking for a child, but it's hard to remember for sure since this question is almost 4 years old. Either way, the question and answer cover both children and descendants, and there are also answers that cover specifically children and not descendants, so I'm not sure what you're trying to get at.

Comment: Oh it's just that when using a search engine to look for a question specifically about looking for an element with a child matching a selector this is the one it finds so I would've tweaked the question title if it were inaccurate to help other people find the right question in the future.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

You can use the [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function:

```
if($('#popup').find('p.filled-text').length !== 0)
   // Do Stuff
```

Comment: This actually worked as I needed it to, but for reference `if($('#popup').has('p.filled-text').length != 0) {` also works.

Comment: No need to check for 0. 0 is a falsey in js.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 42):

There is a [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) function

```
if($('#popup p').hasClass('filled-text'))
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) funcion of jQuery.

```
$("#text-field").keydown(function(event) {
    if($('#popup').children('p.filled-text').length > 0) {
        console.log("Found");
     }
});
```

`$.children('').length` will return the count of child elements which match the selector.

Comment: `.size()` returns the same as the `.length` property but is slower, so you should replace that.

Comment: Thanks Johnnes for pointing me that out! I didn't know it. Answare updated!

Comment: You're welcome, but there is still a mistake. It's `.length` not `.length()`

Comment: :P I thought it was a function like most jQuery interfaces. Kind of inconsistency I think. But well, answare updated once again :P Thanks Johannes.

Comment: The `.length` property is not part of the jQuery library, it's just native javascript. But yes, it can be confusing sometimes.

Comment: "The .find() and .children() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level down the DOM tree."

Answer (score 5):

Simple Way

```
if ($('#text-field > p.filled-text').length != 0)
```

Comment: The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call.

Answer (score 5):

if you have multiple divs with same class and some only have that class you must check each one:

```
            $('.popup').each(function() {
                if ($(this).find('p.filled-text').length !== 0) {
                    $(this).addClass('this-popup-has-filled-text');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a direct child you can do as below if it could be nested deeper remove the >

```
$("#text-field").keydown(function(event) {
    if($('#popup>p.filled-text').length !== 0) {
        console.log("Found");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the 10 years since you've asked this question, jQuery has added almost exactly the `.has(` function that you described above.  It filters the selector it's called on -- and it's faster than using `$('.child').parent('.parent')` and potentially running all the way up the DOM.

```js
$("#text-field").keydown(function(event) {
    if($('#popup').has('p.filled-text').length) {
        console.log("Found");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('.classone')`

- `.find('p .classtwo')` give the child element=p
- `.has('p .classtwo')` give the '.classone' element

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice way to do it

```
if($("#your_id .your_class")) { 
   //Do something
});
```

You can also use ">" if (".your_class") is the only child of the parent ("#your_id") or the first child of the parent ("#your_id")

```
if($("#your_id>.your_class")) { 
   //Do something
});
```

("#your_id") is the parent class or id.
(".your_class") is the class or id you're looking for.