# Jquery loading icons once

Tags: jquery, powerapps

I have a table, where columns name is abbreviation, "UPV". I've created a function where it loads glyphicon question-sign icon explaining the abbreviation on hover.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body > div.wrapper-body > div.page-copy > div > div > div > div > div > div").on("loaded", function() {
            $("th:contains('UPV.')").prepend("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Uzņēmuma prakses vadītājs'></i>");

             $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
             
            $(".glyphicon").css("margin-right", "5px");
    });
});
```

The problem is that, that I have a search function at the top. Each time inputing somethingin the search field and loading it , it loads another loads glyphicon question-sign icon.

Comment: You could add `$("th:contains('UPV.') i.glyphicon ").remove();` before your `$("th:contains('UPV.')").prepend` Also consider showing us your html

Comment: I think I fixed it with .on("loaded", function() { with .one("loaded", function() {, its seemed to fix the issue

Comment: Or you could check if the glyphicon already exists, eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/10539199/2181514