# How can I know if the parent class has this class .child-div using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Please see code below

```html
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    
    <div class="notif-div">Notification Div</div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me regarding this matter, My goal is to find on the
parent div (".parent-div") if has a child class (".child-div"). If my
parent class finds that has a subclass the notif-div class will hide
and if not the notif-div will still show. Using jQuery

Comment: What have you tried so far and why wasn't it working? We can help you debug your code or prepare a concept for it but we will not write it for you.

Comment: You can check your [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539162/using-jquery-to-see-if-a-div-has-a-child-with-a-certain-class).

Comment: @ciekals11 hi thanks for replaying I've tried this so far and still not working but I'm still searching for fix.

$(document).ready(function(){
  var messageNotif = document.querySelector(".message-notif");
  var wrapper = $(this).closest(".menu-notif-cc");
      
        if(wrapper.find(".menu-notif-c._notif-c").hasClass(".menu-notif-c._notif-c")) {
          messageNotif.css("display", "none");
        } else {
         messageNotif.css("display", "initial");
          alert("///");
        }
});

By the way thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question with what you've tried, so that it is formatted correctly.

Comment: Note `.hasClass` takes a class name, not a selector - `$(..).hasClass("class")` not `$("..").hasClass(".class")`

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the info. Currently, I'm working on it

Answer (score 3):

for this you dont need jquery. can be done only with css and the help of *:first-child*.

```css
.parent-div{
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.notif-div {
  display: none;
}

.notif-div:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>3 childs</p>
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    
    <div class="notif-div">Notification Div</div>
</div>

<p>no childs</p>
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="notif-div">Notification Div2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI You can also use `:only-child` then the order of elements doesn't matter.  (or use `:first-child:last-child`)

Comment: Thanks, @JamesDK I didn't know that CSS can do it also.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks also for this answer working on it now.

Comment: @freedomn-m thats a great idea, totally forgot that. thnx

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to note that depending on the security needs of your website, it may be undesirable that the end-user can still see the notification div when they 'view the source HTML' or inspect the element, especially for sensitive data. See the image below.

[image: Notification div still in the DOM after CSS approach]

CSS does not remove elements from the DOM, it only affects them visually. To properly remove the notification div from the DOM, you would have to use Javascript, with jQuery being used in the two scenarios below.

Hide notification div if parent has `.child-div`

```js
if($('.parent-div').find('.child-div').length !== 0)
   $('.notif-div').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div> 
    <div class="notif-div">Notification Div</div>
</div>
```

Show notification div if parent has `.child-div`

```js
if($('.parent-div').find('.child-div').length !== 0)
   $('.parent-div').append($('<div class="notif-div">Notification Div</div>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
var size = $('.parent-div').find('.child-div').length;
if (size !== 0)
    $(".notif-div").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    
    <div class="notif-div">Notification Div</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `nth-of-type` to select the `notif` div.

```css
.notif-div{display: none;}
.parent-div .notif-div:nth-of-type(1) {display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
    
    <div class="notif-div">Notification Div</div>
</div>
```

Here's another div without the `child-div` s

```css
.notif-div{display: none;}
    .parent-div .notif-div:nth-of-type(1) {display: block;}
```

```html
    <div class="parent-div">
        <div class="notif-div">Notification Div</div>
    </div>
```

This will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
if ($('.parent-div').children().hasClass('child-div')){

    $('.parent-div .notif-div').css('display', 'none')

}else{

    $('.parent-div .notif-div').css('display', 'block')

}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-div">
        <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
        <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
        <div class="child-div">This is a child</div>
        
        <div class="notif-div">Notification Div</div>
    </div>
```