# If hasClass then addClass to parent node

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to add new class to the parent class if nodes has a certain class.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".row").hasClass("lock-icon")) {
    $(".row .lock-icon").parent(".content-box").addClass('locked-badge');
  }
});
```

```css
.locked-badge {
  opacity: 0.2;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 mb-5">
  <div class="content-box">

    <div class="row">
      <h3>Some rank name</h3>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="lock-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-lock">lock icon</i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <p class="badges-text">
        Some rank description
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I also have tried this jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $locked = $('.content-box').hasClass('lock-icon');
  $($locked).each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('locked-badge');
  });
});
```

Still not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using jQuery to see if a div has a child with a certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539162/using-jquery-to-see-if-a-div-has-a-child-with-a-certain-class)

Comment: why not do that on the php side as you are running the script in the ready state and not attaching to any events?

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17084871

Comment: `$(".row").hasClass("lock-icon")` - There are no rows with the class `lock-icon` | `$(".row .lock-icon").parent(".content-box")`  - `<div class="lock-icon">` doesn't have a (direct) parent with the class `.content-box` - *[This method](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) is similar to .parents(), except .parent() only travels a single level up the DOM tree*

Comment: try to use `parents` still no good ````if ($(".row .col").hasClass("lock-icon")) {
 $(".row .col .lock-icon").parents(".content-box").addClass('locked-badge');
}````

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth this case is the opposite. I don't looking for the  `hasClass` in parentnode, but in the childrennote then `addClass` to the parents node.

Comment: @AnujShrestha that is mean I have alter the controller. This just for visual.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth your reference still do no good ````if($('.content-box').has('.lock-icon')) {
 $(this).addClass('locked-badge');````

Comment: As I pointed out before, there is not element `.content-box` which has the class `lock-icon`. That is not how hasClass works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to locate the `parent`(s) of the element with the class `lock-icon`, consider trying to find out if the parent has a child with the class `lock-icon`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.content-box').each(function() {
    if ($('.lock-icon', $(this)).length) $(this).addClass('locked-badge');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 mb-5">
  <div class="content-box">

    <div class="row">
      <h3>@lang($badge->rank_name)</h3>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="lock-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-lock">X</i>
        </div>                                      
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <p class="badges-text">
        @lang(html_entity_decode($badge->description))
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to go for `.hasClass()`. Simply target that class and search for `.closest()` parent - in a single line of jQuery:

```js
$(".lock-icon").closest(".content-box").addClass("locked-badge");
```

```js
$(".lock-icon").closest(".content-box").addClass("locked-badge");
```

```css
.locked-badge {
  opacity: 0.2;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 mb-5">
  <div class="content-box">

    <div class="row">
      <h3>Some rank name</h3>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="lock-icon">
          <i class="fa fa-lock">lock icon</i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <p class="badges-text">
        Some rank description
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or, in pure JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".lock-icon").forEach(elLock => {
  elLock.closest(".content-box").classList.add("locked-badge");
});
```